How to subset a SpatRaster using the terra package in R?
I have a raster with multiple categories for which I am only interested in one category (vegClass).
veg <- terra::rast("~/SVTM_NSW_Extant_PCT_vC2_0_M2_0_106/SVTM_NSW_Extant_PCT_vC2_0_M2_0_5m.tif")
activeCat(veg) <- 4 #set category of interest to veg class 
veg


class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1207, 1463, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent      : 142.2135, 142.6199, -31.33736, -31.00208  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat GDA94 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : 1_Second_DEM_MNP_N 
categories  : PCTID, PCTName, vegForm, vegClass, form_PCT, labels 
name        :                    vegClass 
min value   :              Not classified 
max value   : Riverine Sandhill Woodlands 

I want to keep only some values and want to set everything else to NA.
values_to_keep <- c("Stony Desert Mulga Shrublands", "Gibber Chenopod Shrublands", "Inland Rocky Hill Woodlands")

I'm stuck on how to do this. I've tried converting it to a dataframe and filtering but the raster doesn't have xy columns so the coordinate data is lost when I try to convert it back. Any help is appreciated!

You can use subst function from terra package to achieve this like
library(terra)

#Create some raster data
set.seed(0)
veg <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(veg) <- sample(3, ncell(veg), replace=TRUE)
cls <- data.frame(id=1:4, vegClass = c("Stony Desert Mulga Shrublands", 
                                  "Gibber Chenopod Shrublands", 
                                  "Inland Rocky Hill Woodlands",
                                  "Not classified"))

levels(veg) <- cls

#Use subst function to select only intended classes and set others NA
test <- subst(veg, from=c("Stony Desert Mulga Shrublands", 
                    "Gibber Chenopod Shrublands", 
                    "Inland Rocky Hill Woodlands"), 
               to=c("Stony Desert Mulga Shrublands", 
                 "Gibber Chenopod Shrublands", 
                 "Inland Rocky Hill Woodlands"),
               others=NA)


Example data
library(terra)
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
cls <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"))
levels(r) <- cls

To only keep "water" and "urban" you can do
x <- r %in% c("water", "urban")
m <- mask(r, x, maskvalues=FALSE)

